# Automapper flattening of nested object child class

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, nested, automapper

I am trying to perform the following operation with AutoMapper and don't get the expected result.

I have the following configuration:

```
public interface IFlatInterface
{
    public string A {get; set;}
    public string B {get; set;}
    public string C {get; set;}
    public bool D {get; set;}
}


public class ParentObject 
{
    public Data X {get; set;}
    public Measure Y {get; set;} 
}

public class Data 
{
    public string A {get; set;}
    public string B {get; set;}
}

public class Measure
{
    public string C {get; set;}
    public bool D {get; set;}
}
```

I have defined the following mapping rules

```
cfg.CreateMap<IFlatInterface, ParentObject>()
   .ForMember(p => p.Measure, o => o.MapFrom(f => f))
   .ForMember(p => p.Data, o => o.MapFrom(f => f))

cfg.CreateMap<ParentObject, IFlatInterface>()
   .ForMember(i => i.A, o => o.MapFrom(p => p.X.A))
   .ForMember(i => i.B, o => o.MapFrom(p => p.X.B))
   .ForAllOtherMembers(o => o.MapFrom(p.Y))
```

The issue is that the value which is populated is a string "p.Measure" for all the remaining fields. I would like to mapping to happen recursively on the members of Measure. I can't put a extensive rule because different classes can implement IFlatInterface.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: See [this](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/8e15798a8b4facd292feb5fcfbf1e3f7).

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu thanks it seems to do what I am looking for. Do you call it during the initialization of the Mapper of after it is initialized - would you have an example?

Comment: ```CreateMap<ParentObject, IFlatInterface>().Flatten(s=>s.X).Flatten(s=>s.Y)``` or smth :)

Comment: It worked fine ! Thanks for your help @LucianBargaoanu